# What's the easiest way to copy the current URL in Fluid?

Tags: fluid.app

When I'm in a fluid app, and have navigated somewhere, I sometimes want to share that URL with someone.

What's the fastest way to get it onto the clipboard? It seems like it should be simple, but I'm at a loss.

EDIT:  I just figured out that I can turn on "show toolbar", which will add a url bar, but is there a quicker way?  I don't really want it on most of the time and enabling it is a lot more annoying than a cntrl-c.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Developer of [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com) here.

Yes, there's a very easy way:

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> *(That's "Command - L")*

That will temporarily "show" the toolbar (if it was hidden), and select all the text in the URL location field. From there you can copy it, via <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Then, to hide the toolbar, you can press:

<kbd>⎋ esc</kbd> *(That's "Escape")*

If the toolbar was previously hidden, this will hide the toolbar.

Comment: awesome - extra points for all keystrokes!  (I've got another question headed your way here soon...)